# Handling form submission in a jsp page in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC project, an I'm trying to **submit** a form and handle it in the same **jsp page** in order to authenticate the user.

I did authonticate the user by calling a web service built in a **Controller with an ajax request**, but in order to do that without using Ajax this time I got this error `Request method 'POST' not supported`

Here is my code:

The form

```
<form action="/gethealthy/isuser" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
  <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

JSP code

```
if (request.getParameter("username") != null) {  
      HomeController aHomeController = new HomeController();
      String username = request.getParameter("username");
      String password = request.getParameter("password");
      String result = aHomeController.isUser(username, password);
      if (aHomeController.isUser(username, password)) {
        String redirectURL = "project/dashboard";
        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
      } else {
            out.print("Wrong credentials");
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to map your controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: but I told you, I don't want to access the controller.
Is it possible to do that in the view ?

Comment: I know I know, but I have a problem and I guess that I can't solve it another way. I expect 3 different results that will do different actions.

Comment: but thanks anyway, I figured a way to do what I want to :D. I used my web service to response with a GET parameters, then the actions will be taken according to these parameters.